# npm: '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file

Tags: node.js, npm

An attempt to install a package through npm results in the following odd error, seemingly not related to this specific package:

```
C:\Users\User\Documents\Apps and Stuff\App> npm install -g ethnode
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethnode
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c ./cli.js -d 
npm ERR! '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
npm ERR! operable program or batch file.
```

It does not matter from which directory I try to install it (I have tried a path without spaces) or is there a global installing or not.

Windows 10, Node.js v.16.10.0, npm v.7.24.0.

Can anybody provide a hint about what is going on here?

Comment: I suspect `./cli.js' might need to be '.\cli.js\ cos of windows slashes... not sure how to help though